# onChange in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to react.js. I am little bit confused about onChange event in react.js. Why we are not using brackets while handling the event through onChange event?

```
<input 
  type="text"
  onChange={this.handleChange()}
/>
```

Normally when we handle the event through JavaScript we would write like this

```
<input type="text" onclick="handleChange()"/>
```

Comment: looks like you are missing the examples...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean why we need to do `onChange={this.handleChange}` instead of `onChange={this.handleChange()}` - the first one makes gives a *reference* of handleChange to the onChange. The second one immediately (as it is interpreted) runs the handleChange function and the *return value* of that is saved as a referece for the onChange.

Think about it like this

```
onClick={alert(123)} // this runs alert immediately
onClick={() => alert(1)} // makes a new function will run when clicked
onClick={alert} // this runs alert when clicked
```

If you need the `event` object of in your event handler, think about where you would get that from; you need to get it as a function parameter and for that you need a new function or reference:

```
onClick={console.log} // logs the event object
onClick={(event) => console.log(event)} // also logs the event
onClick={console.log(event)} // runs immediately, event doesn't exist then
```

When you have an inline event handler like `onclick="handleChange()"` your browser actually evaluates the string `"handleChange()"` as you press. Like with the `eval()` function. Try doing `eval("alert()")` in dev tools and do note that there "alert()" is a string

PS. Welcome to SO! Please check the formatting of your question next time :)